# Получить результат в квадратных скобках, внутри квадратных скобок

Tags: php, api

Пытаюсь из этого запроса получить, что внутри sourse, но не получается

```
{"success":true,"found":2,"result":[{"sources":["Edmodo"],"email_only":0,"line":"testmail@mail.com:password1","last_breach":"2017-05"},{"sources":["Anijan"],"email_only":0,"line":"testmail@mail.com:password","last_breach":"2019-11"}]}
```

Вот этим кодом,

```
$get = "{"success":true,"found":2,"result":[{"sources":["Edmodo"],"email_only":0,"line":"killerkorndawg@gmail.com:Cornwell24","last_breach":"2017-05"},{"sources":["Anijan"],"email_only":0,"line":"killerkorndawg@gmail.com:Cornwell24","last_breach":"2019-11"}]}";

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($get->result);$i++){
preg_match("/(.*):/", $get->result[$i]->line,$a);
$login = $a[1];
preg_match("/:(.*)/", $get->result[$i]->line,$b);
$pass = $b[1];

preg_match("/\[(.*)\]/",$get->result[$i]->sources,$c);
$base = $c[1];
}
```

Получить, что внутри line получилось, а вот что внутри source - нет, как можно это решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$decodedData = json_decode($data, true)['result'];
foreach($decodedData as $element) {
    echo $element['line'] . "<br>";
    print_r($element['sources']);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно записать в отдельный массивы, что находится в line
В один массив, что находится до двоеточия, в второй, что после

Comment: @nazarstar не вижу проблем. Создай два массива и записывай внутри цикла каждый элемент в свой массив.......... Вопрос изначально был: как достать данные. Вот они достаются спокойно. Расфасовать куда-то это уже другое.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно получить массив записей, состоящих их `line` и `sources`:

```php
$results = json_decode($get)->result;
$cleanData = [];
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $cleanData[] = [
        'line' => $result->line,
        'sources' => $result->sources[0],
    ];
}
```

Результат получится таким:

```php
[
    [
        'line' => 'testmail@mail.com:password1',
        'sources' => 'Edmodo'
    ],
    [
        'line' => 'testmail@mail.com:password',
        'sources' => 'Anijan'
    ]
]
```